# Update inherited class if they are not correct according to what I try to achieve in the `__init__` function

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Is there a way of updating an inherited class in the `__init__` function? Trying to create a hidden sum within a block cipher, so have a class called `BlockCipher`, `SBox` (for the substitution layer), `PBox` (for the mixing layer) and `Key` (for the key layer). So

```
class BlockCipher(SBox, PBox, Key):
    [code here]
```

However, if I want the cipher to be vulnerable to attacks I may have to change the initial values of `SBox`, `PBox` and `Key`. May have to do it thousands of times. Should I just create the ToyCipher and then modify `self.S`, `self.S_I`(for inverse) and so on or is there a way to do it in the `__init__` function when calling `ToyCipher`?

Comment: This may be the result of me not being familiar with the domain, but I can't figure out what "changing the initial values" means here.  Are you sure subclassing is the way to represent what you're trying to do?  Having a bit more code that shows the attributes of these classes might help.

Comment: As of now if I inherent `SBox` for example and I will randomly generate a new acceptable substitution layer, but that does not bean that it is vulnerable to the attack. So may have to update it and check if it is. Can provide a bit more code in a few hours, had to go to school go and this is what I remembered at the top of my head. But the problem itself is that all the classes that I inherited creates some list or dictionary. Say `self.S = {0:2, 1:1, 2:0}`. But If this is not attackable in terms of PBox that may be `self.P = [[1,1,0][0,1,0][1,1,1]]` one or both have to be updated

Comment: This sounds like `SBox` and `PBox` should be mutable attributes rather than parent classes.

Comment: @Samwise Yes I arrived at the same conclusion